# I don't know how to open links in a new tab in html

Tags: html

I don't know what is the code for opening links in a new tab, I only know the code to open links in the current tab, can you give me the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `window.open("url")` with JavaScript to open a link in a new tab.

You can also use `target="_blank"` within the html  tag as well if you don't want to use JS.

Answer (score 0):

In the element put `target="_blank"` so for example:

```
<a class="your-classes" href="https://yoursite.com/here" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 0):

A target attribute with the value of “_blank” opens the linked document in a new window or tab.

```
<a href="https://www.sitename.com" target="_blank">blablabla</a>
```